# Input required ajax post

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать обязательный `input` при выполнении `post` формы `ajax`?

```js
function saveorder() {
var waiter = document.getElementById('waiter');
var waiter_value = waiter.options[waiter.selectedIndex].text;
var client = document.getElementById('client');
var client_value = client.options[client.selectedIndex].text;
var type = document.getElementById('type');
var type_value = type.options[type.selectedIndex].text;
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "addorder.php",
                data: {
                     waiter: waiter_value,
                     client: client_value,
                    type: type_value
                      },
                success: function(html) {
                        $("#response3").empty();
$("#orders").load("orders.php");
$("#div222").load("ord_table.php");
                        $("#response3").append(html);
                }
        }); 
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" required>
<input type="button" onclick="saveorder();" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо дать форме возможность почувствовать, что начинается процесс ее отправки.

```js
function saveorder(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var waiter = document.getElementById('waiter');
  var waiter_value = waiter.options[waiter.selectedIndex].text;
  var client = document.getElementById('client');
  var client_value = client.options[client.selectedIndex].text;
  var type = document.getElementById('type');
  var type_value = type.options[type.selectedIndex].text;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "addorder.php",
    data: {
      waiter: waiter_value,
      client: client_value,
      type: type_value
    },
    success: function(html) {
      $("#response3").empty();
      $("#orders").load("orders.php");
      $("#div222").load("ord_table.php");
      $("#response3").append(html);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="saveorder(event)" method="post">
  <input type="text" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин Пожалуйста. Успехов!